# Socket is closed on write stream but not when reading

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I recently noticed in my multi threaded Java socket handler that I was getting exceptions when I tried to write on a socket, however I was still receiving data via reads.  It was my understanding that if the socket was closed the input stream reader would also throw a socket closed exception when attempting the next read.  Is this not the case and should I manually close the socket if I get this exception when attempting to write?

Comment: The two snippets of code you post really don't tell us anything. It is completely possible to close the `OuputStream` and not the `InputStream`. It's also possible for the remote peer to shut down the socket and writes will fail while reads are still pulling from the TCP or application buffer.

Comment: Ok Brian Roach.  I wasn't sure if they would but thought I would post them this in case.

Comment: Just saying that without more specifics or example code that reproduces the issue, there's a lot of reasons for the behavior you're describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TCP connection can be closed in the write direction but not in the read direction, such a connection is called "[half closed](https://superuser.com/a/615971/94136)". You should keep reading the rest of the data the other side sent, otherwise the connection will not close normally.

If you think about it, how else could you sanely shut down a TCP connection? If you shut it all the way down in one step, what happens if the other side sends some data to you before you finish shutting it down? You still need to receive it. But, obviously, you can't keep sending data.